# Drawing board/grid with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, 2d

I'm writing a small boardgame for Mac OS X using Cocoa. I the actual grid is drawn as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    for (int x=0; x < GRIDSIZE; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < GRIDSIZE; y++) {          

            float ix = x*cellWidth;
            float iy = y*cellHeight;

            NSColor *color = (x % 2 == y % 2) ? boardColors[0] : boardColors[1];
            [color set];

            NSRect r = NSMakeRect(ix, iy, cellWidth, cellHeight);

            NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
            [path appendBezierPathWithRect:r];

            [path fill];
            [path stroke];  
        }
    }   
}
```

This works great, except that I see some errors in colors between the tiles. I guess this is due to some antialiasing or similar. See screenshots below (hopefully you can also see the same problems... its some black lines where the tiles overlap):

[image: rendered board]

**Therefore I have these questions:**

1. Is there any way I can remove these graphical artefacts while still maintaining a resizable/scalable board?
2. Should I rather use some other graphical library like Core Graphics or OpenGL?

**Update:**

```
const int GRIDSIZE = 16;
cellWidth = (frame.size.width / GRIDSIZE);
cellHeight = (frame.size.height / GRIDSIZE);
```

Comment: Using a non-retina macbook pro, I can't see the artifacts you're talking about.  Out of curiosity, what are the values for GRIDSIZE, cellWidth and cellHeight?  Usually this kind of error comes down to pixel boundaries.

Comment: I have updated with the values. I am using a macbook air, i.e. no retina myself. Typically, the artefacts are a dark line on the right and bottom side of all red boxes (where red and green overlaps), and if you look closely it appears to be a bright line on the other sides. It is really annoying, especially in my current window size as the gridsize, cellwidth an cellheight should be numbers that reflect actual pixels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want crisp rectangles you need to align coordinates so that they match the underlying pixels. `NSView` has a method for this purpose: `- (NSRect)backingAlignedRect:(NSRect)aRect options:(NSAlignmentOptions)options`. Here's a complete example for drawing the grid:

```
const NSInteger GRIDSIZE = 16;

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    for (NSUInteger x = 0; x < GRIDSIZE; x++) {
        for (NSUInteger y = 0; y < GRIDSIZE; y++) {
            NSColor *color = (x % 2 == y % 2) ? [NSColor greenColor] : [NSColor redColor];
            [color set];
            [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self rectOfCellAtColumn:x row:y]];
        }
    }
}

- (NSRect)rectOfCellAtColumn:(NSUInteger)column row:(NSUInteger)row {
    NSRect frame = [self frame];
    CGFloat cellWidth = frame.size.width / GRIDSIZE;
    CGFloat cellHeight = frame.size.height / GRIDSIZE;
    CGFloat x = column * cellWidth;
    CGFloat y = row * cellHeight;
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(x, y, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    NSAlignmentOptions alignOpts = NSAlignMinXNearest | NSAlignMinYNearest |
            NSAlignMaxXNearest | NSAlignMaxYNearest ;
    return [self backingAlignedRect:rect options:alignOpts];
}
```

Note that you don't need `stroke` to draw a game board. To draw pixel aligned strokes you need to remember that coordinates in Cocoa actually point to lower left corners of pixels. To crisp lines you need to offset coordinates by half a pixel from integral coordinates so that coordinates point to centers of pixels. For example to draw a crisp border for a grid cell you can do this:

```
NSRect rect = NSInsetRect([self rectOfCellAtColumn:column row:row], 0.5, 0.5);
[NSBezierPath strokeRect:rect];
```

Comment: Could you tell what happens?

Comment: The board is drawn, but with the same white and black lines as if the tiles are overlapping or have gaps.

Comment: I added drawRect so source code so that it should be easy to copy-paste and try. If it still doesn't work I'm puzzled.

Comment: I copy pasted that code, still same problem. all the red rects have a white vertical line on the left border and black vertical line on the right border.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36487/discussion-between-pasi-heikkinen-and-invictus)

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure your stroke color is not black or gray. (You're setting `color` but is that stroke or fill color? I can never remember.)

Second, what happens if you simply fill with green, then draw red squares over it, or vice-versa?

There are other ways to do what you want, too. You can use the [`CICheckerboardGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICheckerboardGenerator) to make your background instead.

Alternately, you could also use a [`CGBitmapContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) that you filled by hand.

Comment: The CICheckerboardGenerator is interesting. I am currently drawing each square as I am going to have some exceptions where the tile color is different depending on the state of the game (e.g. mouse over, clicked, etc). Perhaps the CICheckerboardGenerator and the "fill green first then red" is not a good fit if one of the green tiles suddenly need to be blue?

Comment: I would think you could still manually fill in single squares with any of the above versions.

Comment: Fair enough, but I am still interested in what I did wrong in the first place as I may encounter the same problems when drawing other shapes as well.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you don't actually want your rectangles to have a border, you shouldn't call `[path stroke]`.

Second, creating a bezier path for filling a rectangle is overkill. You can do the same with `NSRectFill(r)`. This function is probably more efficient and I suspect less prone to introduce rounding errors to your floats – I assume you realize that your floats must not have a fractional part if you want pixel-precise rectangles. I believe that if the width and height of your view is a multiple of `GRIDSIZE` and you use `NSRectFill`, the artifacts should go away.

Third, there's the obvious question as to how you want your board drawn if the view's width and height are not a multiple of `GRIDSIZE`. This is of course not an issue if the size of your view is fixed and a multiple of that constant. If it is not, however, you first have to clarify how you want the possible remainder of the width or height handled. Should there be a border? Should the last cell in the row or column take up the remainder? Or should it rather be distributed equally among the cells of the rows or columns? You might have to accept cells of varying width and/or height. What the best solution for your problem is, depends on your exact requirements.

You might also want to look into other ways of drawing a checkerboard, e.g. using `CICheckerboardGenerator` or creating a pattern color with an image (`[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:yourImage]`) and then filling the whole view with it.

There's also the possibility of (temporarily) turning off anti-aliasing. To do that, add the following line to the beginning of your drawing method:

```
  [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setShouldAntialias:NO];
```

My last observation is about your general approach. If your game is going to have more complicated graphics and animations, e.g. animated movement of pieces, you might be better off using OpenGL.

Comment: I have really tried all of this but I still et those errors. I am giving this up. I would never imagine that drawing squares would be so difficult. Still, thank you for your input.

Comment: Everything I have written in my answer I have verified using the code that you provided in your question and I've had no problems getting rid of the artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 6, you can generate a checkerboard pattern using `CICheckerboardGenerator`.

You'll want to guard against the force unwraps in here, but here's the basic implementation:

```
var checkerboardImage: UIImage? {
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICheckerboardGenerator")!

    let width = NSNumber(value: Float(viewSize.width/16))
    let center = CIVector(cgPoint: .zero)
    let darkColor = CIColor.red
    let lightColor = CIColor.green
    let sharpness = NSNumber(value: 1.0)

    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(width, forKey: "inputWidth")
    filter.setValue(center, forKey: "inputCenter")
    filter.setValue(darkColor, forKey: "inputColor0")
    filter.setValue(lightColor, forKey: "inputColor1")
    filter.setValue(sharpness, forKey: "inputSharpness")

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, from: viewSize)
    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)

    return uiImage
}
```

[Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICheckerboardGenerator)

Answer (score 1):

Your squares overlap. `ix + CELLWIDTH` is the same coordinate as `ix` in the next iteration of the loop.

You can fix this by setting the stroke color explicitly to transparent, or by not calling `stroke`.

```
[color set];
[[NSColor clearColor] setStroke];
```

or

```
[path fill];
// not [path stroke];
```

Comment: Actually,its better, but the artefacts is still visible. I guess I must try to adjust the position calculation somehow.

Comment: Could it be caused by lack of precision when doing floating point calculations?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Try `cellWidth = width / GRIDSIZE - 0.1;`